# Software reference for combinatorial design

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

If one were to require quick and easy access to sizeable latin squares, room squares, Steiner systems, designs, balanced block designs... where to look, what software to use?

Comment: you could try Sage: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/designs/design_catalog.html

Comment: You can try sage online in a browser: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/